# Plot area getting cropped out in the final graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to draw a continuous plot with the last 10 data points from the dataset

```
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.ion()
ls1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
l1,= plt.plot([])
a=[]
if 1:
    count=4
    while True:
        x=count%4
        count+=1
        print x
        ls1.append(x)
        l1.set_data(range(10),ls1[-10:])

        #ax.set_xlim(-2,12)?
        #ax.set_ylim(0,5)? this throws error as ax is not defined and I am unable to define it

        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.5)
        
        #plt.show()
        sleep(0.5)
```

[Output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGjIN.png)
As you can see, the output graph's axes are limited in the range [-0.06,+0.06] whereas my output has xlim=[0,10] and ylim=[0,4].
How do I implement those limits to get the correct graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a figure and then use the axes commands. This is a possible solution:

```
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plt.ion()
ls1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
fig = plt.figure() # define a Figure
ax = fig.gca()    # get the ax
l1,= ax.plot([])
a=[]
if 1:
    count=4
    while True:
        x=count%4
        count+=1
        print(x)
        ls1.append(x)
        l1.set_data(range(10),ls1[-10:])

        ax.set_xlim(-2,12) # now ax is defined
        ax.set_ylim(0,5) 

        plt.draw()
        plt.show()
        plt.pause(0.5)

        sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ax` often refers to the variable where we put the [`Axe(s)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) of a plot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#or:
ax = plt.gca()
```

You didn't declare it in your code. [Check here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib-pyplot-subplots) the `subplots()` method.

To force the x and y boundaries, you can either do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10), ls1[-10:])
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,4)
# ...
plt.show()
```

... or:

```
plt.plot(range(10), ls1[-10:])
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 4)
# ...
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. It looks like this is still giving the same problem. The other solution provided by @LuigoFavaro works correctly.